# Can a vector after adding a non-zero vector still be itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am trying to disprove the statement. Suppose $x,y \in V$, where $V$ is a vector space.

If $x+y=x$, I know any vector in vector space must have an additive inverse, $-x$. So I could add $-x$ to both sides.

$$x+y+(-x)  = x+(-x) = 0
$$

so $y = 0$.

I think I disprove it, but feel a bit odd. Can someone verify for me?

Comment: This is perfectly fine, @BlackTea.

Comment: The argument uses the associative and commutative properties of vector addition, as well as additive identity and inverses.  You could use the same argument with any binary operation having those properties, i.e. any abelian group.

Comment: The negative answer to the question is: adding a non-zero vector produces a different vector, or if $y\neq0$ then $x+y\neq x$. This is the [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) of what you proved. Contrapositives are logically equivalent to the original claims, and often are easier to prove than them.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, what you're doing is totally fine, but if you feel like you're cheating here, just write it out in components (assuming a choice of basis and that $\dim(V)$ is finite:
$$
\begin{align*}
& \quad\;\; x + y = x \\
& \Leftrightarrow x + y - x = x - x \\
& \Leftrightarrow (x_1, \ldots, x_n) + (y_1,\ldots, y_n) - (x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (x_1,\ldots, x_n) - (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \\
& \Leftrightarrow (x_1+y_1-x_1, \ldots, x_n+y_n-x_n) = (x_1-x_1,\ldots, x_n-x_n) \\
& \Leftrightarrow (y_1, \ldots, y_n) = (0, \ldots, 0) \\
& \Leftrightarrow y = 0
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Tempted to down-vote this. All that was assumed was that $V$ is a vector space, not $\Bbb{F}^n$ for some field. Yes, certain vector spaces can be put into correspondence with $\Bbb{F}^n$, where $\Bbb{F}$ is the scalar field (i.e. finite-dimensional spaces, which the question does not assume), but the existence of such correspondences is far heavier lifting than this question requires. Answers like these encourage students to run back to coordinates, which discourages them from properly understanding vector spaces in the abstract.

Comment: @TheoBendit Sure, hence my caveat that one assumes a basis can be chosen and $V$ is finite-dimensional. But given the question, it seems like OP is asking for help gaining intuition, not a real proof (since they have already constructed a perfectly valid proof). Intuition builds from concrete examples, the more accessible the better, which was my motivation for posting this as an answer. Totally agree a reliance on coordinates is bad in the long run, but I don't agree it's bad to appeal to them early on to help see what's going on in simple cases.